# A way to print to a network printer using both ethernet and wifi simultaneously

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, ethernet, printer

I was wondering if there was a way to connect my Brother network printer in a way that lets users print using both the ethernet and wifi simultaneously?

I know that Brother specifically states on their site that you cannot use ethernet and wifi at the same time but I was just wondering if there's any other way around this to make it work aside from buying another printer.

Thank you.

Comment: Connect the printer to the ethernet; use your existing wifi, also connected to the same ethernet. Voilà, both work.

Comment: They say no to **connect** the printer itself with both. But clients printing to it in the same network can be connected one way or the other. typically at home we use only a small router so everything is in the same network, typically.

Comment: In general, it's not possible, if the documentation says so. But there might be some workarounds. What exactly do you want to achieve? What's your goal?

Comment: so because it needs to be one or the other, users cannot print to it if they're connected to the wifi network and have to find an open ethernet station to print. it would be great if the users don't have this problem and can print to the printer no matter if they're using wired or wifi.

Comment: If the printer is on ethernet it has no idea whether the client is on ethernet, wifi, or remoting in from Venezuela - it receives a print request over ethernet. My printer can actually do both at once, but I don't, because i don't want to expose yet another interface directly to the airwaves.

Comment: So how would I print to the ethernet connected printer over wifi? I can't even add the printer because it's set to ethernet. The printer setting literally states wifi status - disabled.

Comment: It says that, yes, but that only refers to the _immediate_ connection and not to indirect connections. Doesn't your Ethernet cable go to a "wireless router" that links said Ethernet connection to your normal WiFi network? The printer cannot _in any way_ prevent that from being used.

Comment: If it can't find it by any other method, add it as an IP address. Device thinks it's talking to wifi, printer thinks it's listening to ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise all the comments to your question, here's what you need to do to use the printer with both wired and wireless connections.

1. Connect the printer to an Ethernet port on your WiFi router.
2. Give the printer a static IP address outside the DHCP range, or reserve an address for it on the DHCP server. In home situations, the DHCP server is usually the router.
3. Make sure the router does not isolate wired from WiFi connections. If both have the same IP address range (e.g. 192.168.0.x or 10.0.0.x) it will work fine. That is the case with most routers. If the address ranges are different, set the router up to bridge them.
4. Install the printer on the PCs, using either the Brother software to find it on the network, or installing it as a local printer and creating a Standard TCP/IP port for it (with the printer's IP address).

These instructions are generic. Exact setup details depend on the make and model of your router and your printer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it doesn't make any difference how the printer connects to the router (Ethernet or WiFi).  And it doesn't make any difference how the different computers connect to the router (Ethernet or WiFi).  As long as everything is connected to the network one way or another, there is a path between any computer and the printer.  Anybody can print using either type of connection.  There is nothing gained by connecting directly to the printer via both Ethernet and WiFi, and it sounds like the printer can't support both connections at the same time.

Comment: @fixer1234 You are correct, but I don't like WiFi for printers, it causes too many problems. Also, a printer doesn't normally move around, so just position it near the router and plug it in. And yes, PCs can also use either.